# How do I enable error logging in my Rails production logs?

Tags: logging, ruby-on-rails-5, config, unicorn, production

I'm using Rails 5 behind Unicorn.  When I run visit a particular page on my production instance of my app, I get an error

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

When I look in my myproject/log/production.log file, I see the request, but no explanation of why the error occurred ...

```
Started GET "/my_objects/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&first_name=Dave&last_name=&my_object=&x=12&y=13" for 96.84.106.123 at 2017-12-29 15:34:20 -0500
Processing by my_objectsController#search as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "first_name"=>"Dave", "last_name"=>"", "my_object"=>"", "x"=>"12", "y"=>"13"}
  Rendering my_objects/search.html.erb within layouts/my_object
  Rendered my_objects/_search.html.erb (1.3ms)
```

How do I enable the errors to appear in my log file?  Below is how my logger is configured in my ./config/environments/production.rb file ...

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like
  # NGINX, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  config.cache_store = :memory_store, { size: 32.megabytes }

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

  config.serve_static_files = true
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
  # Comment out the two lines withinn here so taht queries can be seen in the console
  config.after_initialize do
    ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Rails.logger.clone
    ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = Logger::INFO
  end

  config.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(config.paths['log'].first, 1, 50 * 1024 * 1024)

  # This is the classpath where we expect to find JAR files that will help decode Word documents.
  config.java_class_path = "/usr/java/share/poi-3.16/poi-3.16.jar:/usr/java/share/poi-3.16/poi-ooxml-3.16.jar:/usr/java/share/poi-3.16/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.16.jar:/usr/java/share/poi-3.16/ooxml-lib/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar:/usr/java/share/poi-3.16/poi-scratchpad-3.16.jar:/usr/java/share/poi-3.16/lib/commons-collections4-4.1.jar:."

end
```

Comment: Very odd, its not even logging in Rails. Something tells me its not Rails specific error or else logger would have logged it. Worth checking Unicorn server logs. Keep me updated. :thumbsup:

Comment: Just some ideas, probably mostly useless: have you restarted the Unicorn server; is there a lag between actions and log entries (due to buffering), meaning you don't see the error in the log immediately; does it make a difference if you comment out the `config.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new...` line?